# Acts as commentable with threading example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, acts-as-commentable

I'm new to Rails and am currently developing a blog.  I want to know if there is a tutorial on how to use Acts as commentable with threading, since the only instructions to use from the GitHub are to add `acts_as_commentable` to your model.

1. How should I create the form for new comments?
2. How can I retrieve all the comments from a model?
3. How do I configure the routes in order to show comments?
4. How do I modify my controllers to make this feature available?

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_nested_set :scope => [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]
#attr_accessible :commentable, :body, :user_id
validates :body, :presence => true
validates :user, :presence => true

# NOTE: install the acts_as_votable plugin if you
# want user to vote on the quality of comments.
#acts_as_votable

belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

# NOTE: Comments belong to a user
belongs_to :user

# Helper class method that allows you to build a comment
# by passing a commentable object, a user_id, and comment text
# example in readme
def self.build_from(obj, user_id, comment)
new \
  :commentable => obj,
  :body        => comment,
  :user_id     => user_id
end

#helper method to check if a comment has children
def has_children?
   self.children.any?
end

# Helper class method to lookup all comments assigned
# to all commentable types for a given user.
scope :find_comments_by_user, lambda { |user|
where(:user_id => user.id).order('created_at DESC')
}

# Helper class method to look up all comments for
# commentable class name and commentable id.
scope :find_comments_for_commentable, lambda { |commentable_str, commentable_id|
where(:commentable_type => commentable_str.to_s, :commentable_id =>   commentable_id).order('created_at DESC')
}

# Helper class method to look up a commentable object
# given the commentable class name and id
def self.find_commentable(commentable_str, commentable_id)
  commentable_str.constantize.find(commentable_id)
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you go through the following link in github,

https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable

By Calling this command it will automatically create the forms with migration.

rails g comment

You just need to run the migration.

Which Rails version you are using ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast response, my Rails version is Rails 3.2.13 and when i ran the command it only created a model for the comment. Which I will show in my edited question.